# nestjs- use service from another module in interceptor

Tags: nestjs

I try to use a service provided by another module in my interceptor but not work, I have an error about import.

***SettingService*** is exported correctly by ***SettingModule***, I'm importing ***SettingModule*** in ***FileModule***.

In error, it talked about ***BannerModule*** but don't know why, ***BannerModule*** is running without any errors. If I remove references to ***SettingService*** in Interceptor the error is not displayed.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong ??
Thank you.

Error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the 71bae409-6553-4d7b-b555-1dbff55f4584 (ConfigService, FileService, ?). Please make sure that the argument SettingService at index [2] is available in the BannerModule context.
<--------- don't know why it talk about BannerModule... ??
Potential solutions:
- If SettingService is a provider, is it part of the current BannerModule?
- If SettingService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BannerModule? 
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing SettingService */ ]
  })
```

setting.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    QueueModule.forRoot(),
    MongoDBModule,
    forwardRef(() => UserModule),
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    forwardRef(() => FileModule),
    forwardRef(() => MailerModule)
  ],
  providers: [
    ...settingProviders,
    ...menuProviders,
    SettingService,
    MenuService
  ],
  controllers: [
    SettingController,
    SettingFileUploadController,
    AdminSettingController,
    MenuController
  ],
  exports: [...settingProviders, ...menuProviders, SettingService, MenuService]
})
export class SettingModule {
  constructor(private settingService: SettingService) {
    this.settingService.syncCache();
  }
}
```

file.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongoDBModule, 
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    forwardRef(() => SettingModule)
  ],
  providers: [...fileProviders, FileService, ImageService, FileVideoService],
  controllers: [FileController],
  exports: [...fileProviders, FileService, ImageService, FileVideoService]
})
export class FileModule {}
```

file.interceptor.ts

```
class MixinInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
      private readonly config: ConfigService,
      private readonly fileService: FileService,
      private readonly settingService: SettingService,
    ) {
      ...
      this.settingService.getKeyValue(...)
    }
```

Comment: It seems that I need to import Settingsertvice too in all modules where I'm using the Interceptor but don't understand why...

Comment: @nikash why not ? Where is the interceptor supposed to find the `SettingService` then ? If you don't want to inject the `SettingService` everywhere, you might want to consider putting it in a module annotated `@Global`. For example, you can annotate the `SettingModule`with `@Global`

Comment: Of course, I supposed that if I import SettingService in FileModule, Interceptor found it ut not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you just need to add the `SettingsModule` to the `imports` of the `BannerModule`. More than likely, you're using this `MixinInterceptor` inside the `BannerController` and Nest is trying to create an instance of it in the context of the `BannerModule`. We would need to see your code to verify that, so for now I'm just running on my assumptions based on the error